# SQL Server Database not being created by Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework

I'm trying out Entity Framework 6.1.3 on Visual Studio .Net 2013 Community Edition. The problem is the database is not being created and the property that is of type DBSet is always set to Nothing.

Here is my class

```
Public Class ExpenseType
    Public Property ExpensTypeId As Integer
    Public Property ExpenseName As String
    Public Property IsOutgoing As Boolean
End Class
```

Here is my Context Class

```
Imports System.Data.Entity

Public Class ExpensesContext
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Property ExpenseTypes As DbSet(Of ExpenseType)
End Class
```

Here is my Form code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using db As New ExpensesContext
        Dim expensetype As New ExpenseType With
        {
                .ExpensTypeId = 0,
                .ExpenseName = "ADDITIONAL FUND",
                .IsOutgoing = False
        }

        **** value of ExpensesTypes is Nothing and generates NullReferenceException
        db.ExpenseTypes.Add(expensetype)
        db.SaveChanges()
    End Using
End Sub
```

My connection string (inside App.Config)

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ExpensesContext" 
         connectionString="Server=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=ExpensesTracking" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I forgot to place the PROPERTY in the DBSet variable.